# Integrate $\int r^n \sin r \,dr$

Tags: integration, analysis

How to compute $\int r^n \sin r\, dr, n\in \Bbb Z$? In fact, I really need 10 reputation points to ask a complex question.

Comment: Do you know how to use integration by parts?

Comment: @B.Pasternak   $\int uv'=uv-\int u'v$

Comment: @B.Pasternak it seem useless

Comment: So use integration by parts with $u=r^n$, $v=\sin r$, then repeat until the last time you have $u=r^1$. This works for $n\in\Bbb Z, n>0$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I want a result include n, not do it  after know what n is ,

Comment: @lanse7pty It is certainly not useless. I think it's the cleanest approach, avoiding Taylor series.

Comment: @lanse7pty Your answer will include $n$. Also, we are all trying to help you.

Comment: For general $n\in\Bbb Z, n>0$, find a recursive formula. Try $n=0,1,2,3,4$, and look for the pattern.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Thanks ,I misunderstand you , sorry.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks.

Comment: Care to share the reason for upvotes? It is one of the standard integration by part exercises...

Comment: Misa no did upvote! I agree with you @vonbrand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $$I_n=\int r^n \sin r \,\ dr$$
$$=-r^n \cos r + n \int r^{n-1} \cos r \,\ dr$$
$$=-r^n \cos r + nr^{n-1} \sin r - n(n-1)\int r^{n-2} \sin r \,\ dr$$
$$=-r^n \cos r + nr^{n-1} \sin r - n(n-1)I_{n-2}$$
So you get this recursion relation $$I_n+ n(n-1)I_{n-2}=-r^n \cos r + nr^{n-1} \sin r $$ which you can solve easily after calculating $I_0$ and $I_1$.

Answer (score 3):

use the taylor series of $\sin r$ to get
$$r^n(r-\frac{r^3}{3!}+\frac{r^5}{5!}-....)=r^{n+1}-\frac{r^{3+n}}{3!}+\frac{r^{5+n}}{5!}-....$$

Comment: it seem to be a good way ,thanks .

Comment: @lanse7pty you r welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can use Taylor series to transform this equation. Then you can integrate this integral much easier.